# Checking if int is not alpha

Tags: c, string, int, structure, isalpha

I have a structure that has

```
int Hour
int Min
int Sec
```

I'm reading string from file. File has text like: 23:21:30 12:32:54

I split whole line to separate times and then I do second split to structure.
I'm doing

```
structure[x].Hour = atoi(token);
```

Then I need to check if **structure[x].Hour** is not alpha.

```
if(isalpha(structure[x].Hour)){//DO Something}
```

is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: check `token`..

Comment: Field `hour` is already an integer. No alphabetic character is possible in an integer. You would need to check your token for alpha character before calling atoi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really ask a question or tell us what problem you have, but I'll help you anyway...

What you are doing is in the wrong order. If you call `atoi` with a non-numeric strings it will return `0`. You then check to see if the integer `0` is not a letter, which it of course isn't. You need to do it in the opposite order: First check that you don't have a non-numeric string (which you have to do in a loop); And *then* convert it to an integer.

This can actually be done in a single standard library function call, but not to `aoti` which doesn't have that support, but with the [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) function.

The [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) function have error checking built in, and support to help you figure out if the whole string was converted or not.